# Play 2.3.x + Webjars + Requirejs And Transitive Dependencies

Tags: angularjs, playframework, requirejs, playframework-2.3, webjars

## Questions:

- Is there a way to avoid manually defining paths and shims in requirejs for webjars and all their transitive dependencies?  (Or at least for webjars that come with a requirejs.config() call)?
- Is there a simple example (or seed) of a Play 2.3 app that uses webjars and requirejs with javascript packages that have transitive dependencies?  (Where each transitive dependency doesn't have to be manually configured with a shim in the app's requirejs config block?)

## Problem Description:

I'm migrating a project to play 2.3 and am running into some issues grok-ing how webjars+requirejs are supposed to integrate.  Simple problem that illustrates my confusion:

I want to use angular-ui-calendar (https://github.com/webjars/angular-ui-calendar), so I add the following to build.sbt:

```
"org.webjars" % "angular-ui-calendar" % "0.8.1"
```

After the update, sbt pulls down the angular-ui-calendar web jar, as well as the dependencies specified in its pom.xml (jquery-ui and fullcalendar).

To use any of it though, I have to add a bunch of paths and shims to main.js containing my requirejs config... basically:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'angular-ui-calendar' : ['../lib/angular-ui-calendar/calendar'],
        'jquery-ui' : ['../lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui']
         /* ... */
    },
    shim: {
        'angular':
           exports: 'angular'
        'angular-ui-calendar':
           deps: ['angular', 'jquery-ui', 'fullcalendar']
           /* ... */
    }
 });
```

If all this manual shimming is necessary, what's the point of the requirejs.config()'s defined in some webjars? (For example: https://github.com/webjars/angular-ui-bootstrap/blob/master/src/main/resources/webjars-requirejs.js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how you use WebJars in Play.  If you follow the [WebJars Docs for Play](http://www.webjars.org/documentation) then you can use the WebJars' RequireJS configs.  The downside of this approach is that it doesn't work with `sbt-rjs`.   If you follow the [Play Docs for WebJars](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Assets) then you have to manually specify the RequireJS config.  Ideally Play should add support for the WebJars' RequireJS configs.

Comment: sbt-rjs turned out to be the problem.  (I was trying to use the WebJars Docs for Play with sbt-rjs enabled.)   I've decided to manually manage requirejs config for the time being and hope that Play! improves support eventually.